# Surface 3 doesn't auto-reconnect to wifi

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro

Everytime I move my surface 3 from work to home, and back to work, the wifi gets stuck on the last network I was connected to. If I leave it on the work connection when I get home (and not reconnect it to my home) the next day I will take it to the office and the connection is stuck at limited.

Sometimes just turning my tablet off, and back on, the restoring of the connection leaves the connection as limited.

So far the only way to reliably get reconnected is either a full reboot, or disconnect/reconnect from the network, or open IE and go through its repair.

My other devices understand auto-connecting, and switching networks, shouldn't my Surface 3 be able to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy created a workaround for this issue. He created a script to automatically toggle the wifi on wake-up and it seems to work well.

Here are the steps:
http://techblog.precisioninfinity.com/2014/06/surface-pro-3-wi-fi-issue-limited.html

Comment: Correction. It worked, I just have to make sure that the script is executed as admin.